# How to determine to use pointer or normal variable in function argument?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct contact {
    char name[30];
    int phone_number;
    char address [30];
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct contact friend;
    strcpy(friend.name, "Jane Doe");
    friend.phone_number = 377177377;
    strcpy(friend.address, "3771 University Avenue");

    char *name;
    int number;
    char *address;

    update_contact(&friend, name, number, address);
    return 0;

}
```

I need to implement the `update_contact` function to update the contact information. `friend` and `number` are normal variables. `*name` and `*address` are pointers. But the function call also use the address of the pointer `friend`, which is `&friend`. Now I'm very confused on what should I put in the function parameters.

I tried to put pointers in.

```
void update_contact (struct *c, char *name, int number, char *address) {
    c->name = name;
    c->phone_number = number;
    c->address = address;
}
```

However, this comes up with a bunch of errors, such as

```
error: request for member 'address' in something not a structure or union
&c->address = address;
```

How can I fix this? Thank you

This is the fixed version. Thanks Thomas Jager and Some Name.

```
void update_contact (struct contact *c, char *name, int number, char *address) {
    strcpy(c->name, name);
    c->phone_number = number;
    strcpy(c->address, address);
}
```

Comment: `struct *c` in the `update_contract` definition needs to be `struct contact *c`.

Comment: Where is `&c->address = address`?

Comment: @Some Name ahhhh, it should be `strcpy(c->address, address);`

Comment: What is pointed to by `name` and what is pointed to by `address` when you call `update_contact(&friend, name, number, address);`??

Comment: Oh, I forget to add that piece. But it has to be set anyway.

Comment: That was very confusing. As your question was written, once you fixed `update_contact` it looked like you were attempting to pass uninitialized pointers to the function (as well as an uninitialized integer), which would have invoked *Undefined Behavior*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  David C. Rankin suggested:

You need to initialize the variables passed as parameters.
For example

```
char *name = "Donald Trump";
int number = 01010101010;
char *address = "White House;
```

---

```
char name[] = "Donald Trump";
int number = 01010101010;
char address[] = "White House;
```

---

or you can use literals and constants when calling the function

```
  update_contact(&friend, "Donald Trump", 0101010010, "White House");
```

---

```
void update_contact (struct contact *c, char *name, int number, char *address) {
    strcpy(c->name, name);
    c->phone_number = number;
    strcpy(c->address, address);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In function `update_contract`,

1. replace `struct` with `struct contact`
2. use `strcpy`

as follows

```
void update_contact(struct contact *c, char *name, int number, char *address) {
    strcpy(c->name, name);
    c->phone_number = number;
    strcpy(c->address, address);
}
```